# Adding virtual device on Emulator

Tags: android, virtual, emulation

I want to add virtual device on emulator. so I have built SDK on platform source.
And I am searching about goldfish in googling
But I don't know how to approach it.

Please help me anyone, anything.

Thanks,
MW

Comment: emulator is part of android sdk and you can create new avd devices using eclipse. Please follow android guidelines from the website.

Answer (score 2):

Use AVD in Eclipse - Window, AVD Manager.  In here you can see existing devices and create new ones.

[image: AVD in Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

Goldfish is the name given to the virutal Google CPU, which executes instructions ARM926T. This is completely transparent to you when you create a new virtual device, because it is only the internal form in which Google gives life to this device.

regards,